# Laravel. how to get the removedEmployees from mergedEmployees?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

this code is not working: **$removedEmployees = $mergedEmployees->diff($uniqueEmployees);**

here is my code.

```
$employees1 = Employee::where('employment_status', '<>', 'SEPARATED')
    ->where('client_code_1', $client->client_code)
    ->where('position', $grouping->position)
    ->where('billable_rate', $grouping->billable_rate)
    ->get();

$employees2 = Employee::where('employment_status', '<>', 'SEPARATED')
    ->where('client_code_2', $client->client_code)
    ->where('position', $grouping->position)
    ->where('billable_rate', $grouping->billable_rate)
    ->get();

$mergedEmployees = $employees1->merge($employees2);
$uniqueEmployees = $mergedEmployees->unique();
$removedEmployees = $mergedEmployees->diff($uniqueEmployees);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravel merge states

`The merge method merges the given array or collection with the original collection. If a string key in the given items matches a string key in the original collection, the given item's value will overwrite the value in the original collection:`

[see here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-merge)

so this line
`$mergedEmployees = $employees1->merge($employees2);`
is already creating a unique array

as a result, `$mergedEmployees->diff($uniqueEmployees)` results empty

Instead you should do...

```php
$employees1 = Employee::where('employment_status', '<>', 'SEPARATED')
    ->where('client_code_1', $client->client_code)
    ->where('position', $grouping->position)
    ->where('billable_rate', $grouping->billable_rate)
    ->get()->toArray();

$employees2 = Employee::where('employment_status', '<>', 'SEPARATED')
    ->where('client_code_2', $client->client_code)
    ->where('position', $grouping->position)
    ->where('billable_rate', $grouping->billable_rate)
    ->get()->toArray();

$mergedEmployees = array_merge($employees1, $employees2);
$uniqueEmployees = array_unique($mergedEmployees,SORT_REGULAR);


$removedEmployees = collect(array_map('json_decode',array_keys(array_diff_assoc(array_flip(array_map('json_encode', $mergedEmployees)),array_flip(array_map('json_encode', $uniqueEmployees))))));
```

there is a shortcoming here though,it will not handle more then one duplicate, if $mergedEmployees is like array( 1,1,1,2) and $uniqueEmployees is like array( 1,2), the result will be array( 1 )

Comment: Thanks! this will do. the max duplicate is only 2